# How to prove this Dirac Delta Function property?

Tags: proof-verification, dirac-delta

How to prove the equation below, using Dirac Delta function properties?
$$
\delta(x^2-m^2)=\frac{1}{2|w|}(\delta(x-w)+\delta(x+w))
$$
where 
$$
w^2=|x|^2+m^2
$$
I tried to show it using 
$$
\delta(f(x))=\sum\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}
$$
but could not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. As Emilio mentioned I will start with the definition.
$$
\delta(f(x))=\sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}
$$
$$
\delta(x^2-m^2)=\frac{\delta(x-m)+\delta(x+m)}{2|m|}
$$ 
with the transformation $w^2=x^2+m^2$
$$
\delta(x^2-m^2)=\frac{1}{2|m|}(\delta(x-\sqrt {w^2-x^2})+\delta(x+\sqrt{w^2-x^2}))
$$
Let me derive the first and second term, using similar definition 
$$
\delta(f(x))=\frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{|f'(x_0)|}
$$ 
$$
\delta(x-\sqrt {w^2-x^2})+\delta(x+\sqrt{w^2-x^2})= \frac{\delta(x-w)}{\frac{2|w|}{2|m|}}+\frac{\delta(x+w)}{\frac{2|w|}{2|m|}}
$$
and eventually come to the end
$$
\delta(x^2-m^2)=\frac{1}{2|w|}(\delta(x-w)+\delta(x+m))
$$

Answer (score 4):

The starting point is the **[definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function)**:
$$
\delta(f(x))=\sum_i\dfrac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}
$$
where $x_i$ are all the roots of $f(x)$
( the formula in OP is not correct)

For $f(x)=x^2-y^2$ the roots are $x_1=-y$ and $x_2=y$ and $f'(x)=2x$, so we have:

$$
\delta(x^2-y^2)=\dfrac{\delta(x-y)}{2|+y|}+\dfrac{\delta(x+y)}{2|-y|}=\dfrac{\delta(x-y)+\delta(x+y)}{2|y|}
$$

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I will edit the question. Your answer will not be irrelevant but maybe need improvement.

Comment: Now the question is very different. Anyway you have to edit the formula for $\delta(f(x))$.

Comment: In this new formulation we have:$\delta(x^2-m^2)=\delta(2x^2-w^2)$ and the result in OP seems wrong.

Comment: I think so and I am looking for a correct answer. I suppose my textbook have a typo but not sure. I have tried some approximations also, try to understand where this came from.

Comment: Use the correct formula and find: $\delta(2x^2-w^2)=\dfrac{\delta(x-w/\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}|w|}+\dfrac{\delta(x+w/ \sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}|w|}$.

Comment: I would also manipulate $\delta(x-w/\sqrt2)$ using the definition. Where it goes you suppose?

Comment: I don't see any simpler result. But you can post another question.